# upwork-api return 503 ioexception

Tags: java, upwork-api

I created app for getting info from upwork.com. I use java lib and Upwork OAuth 1.0. The problem is local request to API works fine, but when I do deploy to Google Cloud, my code does not work. I get ({"error":{"code":"503","message":"Exception: IOException"}}).

I create UpworkAuthClient for return OAuthClient and next it is used for requests in JobClient.

```
run() {
   UpworkAuthClient upworkClient = new UpworkAuthClient();
   upworkClient.setTokenWithSecret("USER TOKEN", "USER SECRET");
   OAuthClient client = upworkClient.getOAuthClient();

   //set query
   JobQuery jobQuery = new JobQuery();
   jobQuery.setQuery("query");
   List<JobQuery> jobQueries = new ArrayList<>();
   jobQueries.add(jobQuery);

   // Get request of job
   JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(client, jobQuery);
   List<Job> result = jobClient.getJob();
}

public class UpworkAuthClient {
    public static final String CONSUMERKEY = "UPWORK KEY";
    public static final String CONSUMERSECRET = "UPWORK SECRET";
    public static final String OAYTРCALLBACK = "https://my-app.com/main";

    OAuthClient client ;

    public UpworkAuthClient() {
        Properties keys = new Properties();
        keys.setProperty("consumerKey", CONSUMERKEY);
        keys.setProperty("consumerSecret", CONSUMERSECRET);
        Config config = new Config(keys);
        client = new OAuthClient(config);
    }

    public void setTokenWithSecret (String token, String secret){
        client.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
    }

    public OAuthClient getOAuthClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public String getAuthorizationUrl() {
        return this.client.getAuthorizationUrl(OAYTРCALLBACK);
    }
}

public class JobClient {
    private JobQuery jobQuery;
    private Search jobs;

    public JobClient(OAuthClient oAuthClient, JobQuery jobQuery) {
        jobs = new Search(oAuthClient);
        this.jobQuery = jobQuery;
    }

    public List<Job> getJob() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject job = jobs.find(jobQuery.getQueryParam());
        jobList = parseResponse(job);
        return jobList;
    }
}
```

Local dev server works fine, I get resilts on local machine, but in Cloud not. 
I will be glad to any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
{"error":{"code":"503","message":"Exception: IOException"}}
```

doesn't seem like a response return by Upwork API. Could you please provide the full response including the returned headers? So, we will take a more precise look into it.

Comment: Activation of billing in google cloud solved my problem. Thanks